# Conversão múltipla SCCS > SASS

Tags: css, sass

Olá,

Anteriormente, em um projeto meu, fiz mais de duzentos arquivos .scss, e recentemente me adaptei ao uso do .sass. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer a conversão de todos estes arquivos de uma só vez, ao invés de ir um por um e fazendo:

```
$ sass-convert estilo-banner-topo.scss:estilo-banner-topo.sass
```

É possível?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, `sass-convert` aceita um argumento recursivo.

Se você rodar o comando `$ sass-convert --help` ele vai te passar uma lista de opções disponíveis, uma delas é `-R, --recursive` que converte todos os arquivos de um diretório, necessita o uso do `--from` e `--to`.

Sendo assim, seu comando pareceria com algo como isso:

```
$ sass-convert -R sass_dir --from scss --to sass
```

Comment: Perfeito Vinicius, muito obrigado, solucionou o meu problema!